# After editing the video in python using moviepy, I found that the length of the processed video was different than the length of the original video

Tags: python

Video: v-9-2-1-2_1_idle+idle+idle_audio.mp4, original video length: 10.92, edited video length: 10.95, time difference: 0.03

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlRRH.png)
By adding parameters, it is found that the video frame rate and audio sampling frequency have effects on the edited video duration, but still cannot be consistent with the original video length.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.